# Issues in finding elements of the hashtag posts in Instagram

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, instagram

Scenario:

1. Login with username and password
2. Search with hashtag
3. Click on each post and click on like button

Code for searching post and liking:

```
List<WebElement> postlinks = 
driver.findelements("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p')]");
for(int i=0;i<postlinks.size();i++){
postlinks.get(i).click();
Like.click();.  
}
```

My Issue:

Size of `postlinks` is 21 at first but it increases after scrolling. 
Size changes whenever it is scrolled.

Comment: after loop you can again find size of postlink and continue your operation

Comment: give some more info and exception if any

Comment: @Ankur can you share the sode

Comment: @murali am not getting any error. The postlink size is 21 at first. But it increases when page is scrolled

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
List<WebElement> postlinks = 
driver.findelements("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p')]");
```

you are collecting the links, lets say size is 21.

Gone for forLoop

```
for(int i=0;i<postlinks.size();i++){
```

Inside of this performing  some clicks, if you think that it leads to  increase the links but still you are using postlinks  which is fixed 21.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. Can you tell how to avoid this?

Comment: in for loop: try like for(int i=0;i<postlinks.size();i++){
   
   //do you things here..then
   //again
   postlinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p')]"));
   
  }

Comment: Ya same result is coming

Answer (score 0):

Try using `while loop`

```
List<WebElement> postlinks = driver.findelements("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p')]");

// define maximum post count to click
int MaxCount = 40;
int i = 0;

while(i < MaxCount) {
    postlinks.get(i).click();
    Like.click();
    i++;
    if(i == postlinks.size()) // index of 20, 40,... then get new element
        postlinks = driver.findelements("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p')]");
```

Comment: The same thing is happening if I use while also

Comment: so you don't want to have more than 21 links but why? because after 21 it will not clicked.